# Updating notifications on a loop

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-notifications

So I want to start a notification only when x Activity onStop() is called.  But I want to have a loop that updates the notification every second (countdown)

As you can imagine, I want to cancel the notification on the Activity onResume() or on the autocancel for the notification.

As a general Android question, is the only way to do this is with a Service?  Open to any and all suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Wes.   Since the Activity itself is in onStop(), you need something outside the Activity to do a continuing action (the countdown).  A Service is the usual way to accomplish that.

Peter